# Find the number of bound states in a finite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I know how to derive the concrete energy levels in a finite potential well with the typical graphical analysis.

But I want to know if one can do it differently without any complicated math and a computer just by comparing it to the infinite potential well. Is that possible?

For instance consider the following setup: well width $a=0.5$ nm
and potential $V_0=25$ eV with an electron in it.

For an infinite potential well we get the following energy levels for the electron:

- $E_1=1.5$ eV
- $E_2=6.0$ eV
- $E_3=13.5$ eV
- $E_4=24.1$ eV
- $E_5=37.6$ eV
- […]

From the graphical analysis I know that the electron can have 5 bounded states. But could it also have been concluded by looking at the values for the infinite well? For me it’s clear that the energy levels are lower in the finite well, but from that I only see 4 bounded states because we don’t know if the 5th state which will be smaller than 37.6 eV will be under 25 eV.

Can someone help? :)

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question here.  Looking at the infinite well would allow you to conclude that there are at least four bound states in this well but would not allow you to conclude anything about whether there are more than four.